# In WF 4.0, is there any way to have an activity imported through a service reference use Azure endpoint discovery?

Tags: wcf, azure, workflow-foundation

Working with WF, WCF, and the most recent Azure SDK, I have a simple sequential activity, and I have added a service reference and rebuilt the project so my service methods are all imported as activities. So far, so good, but my service will run on the emulator or in the cloud with an internal endpoint, so I need to use RoleEnvironment to discover the endpoint at runtime.

Is there any way I can get the imported activity to do this, or do I just have to write a custom activity? I can't see a way, as the only property the activity exposes is an Endpoint configuration value.

And if I have to write a custom activity, can I pass the endpoint in to my generated activity (so could my custom activity be a wrapper around it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly, to tidy this up: I don't think it is possible. I ended up writing a custom activity to do it, which was straightforward enough.